# Resizing an image from UIImagePickerController not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more?rq=1) post on how to resize an image. I placed the `+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;` in `selectExerciseImageViewController.h` and copied the relevant code to `selectExerciseImageViewController.m`.

Then I attempt to resize the image, save it, and retrieve the saved image file into a `UIImageView`. but for some reason the image is never showing the the `UIImageView` and the last `NSLog` returns `null`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  UIImage* newImage = [selectExerciseImageViewController imageWithImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]
      scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(40.0,40.0)];

    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
    // Give a name to the file
    NSString* imageName = @"MyImage.png";

    // Now, we have to find the documents directory so we can save it
    // Note that you might want to save it elsewhere, like the cache directory,
    // or something similar.
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Now we get the full path to the file
    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    // and then we write it out
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
    //imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    _testimg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
    NSLog(@"asd %@",[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"]);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
> ```

This loads an image from the main application bundle.  You are writing the file to the documents directory.  You need to instantiate the `UIImage` object with a different method.  Try:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];
```

Comment: No, you cannot modify the application bundle, because this is digitally signed and any modifications would make your application fail to start.  Apple provide particular directories for you to write to, you should use these.

Comment: when i check my photo album then i should see a cropped version of my file correct?. How do i get the fullPathToFile??

Comment: No, simply saving an image to disk doesn't automatically add it to any photo albums.  You need to use the correct API for that.

Comment: You already have the `fullPathToFile` - look at the code you have posted.  Did you just copy and paste this from somewhere then ask for help without even reading it?

Comment: No, I just don't know how this works exactly. Thus, I am confused. Thank you :)